# X3dom click away event

Tags: javascript, events, click, x3dom

I am currently using X3DOM to display some 3D models on a webpage.
The point is, I am colouring the models one by one when clicking on them in the canvas and I want it to get their original colour back when clicking away, I mean, still in the X3DOM canvas but not on an X3DOM Node such as a shape or else.

To do that, I need to get the event when I am clicking on the void, or a way to find out that I am not clicking on a shape or anything but still clicking in the x3dom canvas.

That's where I need some help because the only thing I capture when doing :

```
document.onload = function() {

    var $element = document.getElementById("the-one");

    $element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        console.log(event);

    }, false);
};
```

is the click event on the x3dom canvas (`#the-one`) and nothing else, even if I click on a shape (I can do a handler on the onclick event of the shape but it would thus be in a different function and not usable to know if I clicked away I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way somehow :

```
document.onload = function() 
{
    // The X3D element
    var $element = document.getElementById("the-one");

    // Adding the click event
    $element.addEventListener("click", function(event)
    {
        // Get the position of the mouse in the canvas
        var canvasPos = this.runtime.mousePosition(event);

        // Return an array of shape elements contained in a rect on the canvas (x1,y1 and x2,y2)
        var picked = this.runtime.pickRect(canvasPos[0], canvasPos[1], canvasPos[0], canvasPos[1]);

        if (picked.length)
        {
            // do whatever you want
        }

    }, false);
};
```

If there's nothing in the array, then it means the user did not pick any shape.